Finite type must be even?
In several complex variables, there is a notion of finite type for the boundary of a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$. A point $p \in \partial \Omega$ is called of finite type $k$ if any of the following two conditions (they are different notions of finite type but they coincide in 2 dimensions) hold:

The minimum number of commutator of complex tangent vectors at $p$ to span the whole tangent space is $k$ or

The maximum order of contact of a complex curve with the boundary point $p$ is $k$.


People know that if the domain $\Omega$ is pseudoconvex and also of finite type (for every boundary point) then the type of any boundary point must be an even integer. Can anyone tell me how is this number even because of pseudoconvexity ?
